# how to enable horizontal scrolling in atom editor using keystrokes?

Tags: atom-editor

I have long lines of code. But i don't want to use soft wraps because it breaks the nice formatting - and there isn't enough space on my screen anyway.

I want to scroll horizontally - `left or right` based on keystrokes for example:

`ctrl + right arrow`/ `ctrl + left arrow`

**What is the command for horizontal scrolling?**

Or at least be able to press the scroll wheel of the mouse and drag left or right.. like it's possible in the browser sometimes.

Right now i do it with the horizontal bar from the bottom of the editor. It's soo time consuming. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Found it! It's actually very simple: use `shift + scroll wheel`. 
**Couldn't find a keyboard-only solution yet.**

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me crazy. I have no horizontal scroll bar in Atom for some reason. Now I can scroll horizontally without having to hold down the left and right arrow keys. :-)

Comment: Any idea for those that have Logitech mice with horizontal scroll wheels?  It doesn't work by default, I am searching for the answer.  The 'ctrl' is neat, but I'd prefer to use the native solution.